# How do I create a scrollableparallax background in AndEngine GLES1

Tags: android, andengine, parallax-scrolling

In my game I want my background to move side by side as the player moves on screen in AndEngine. I moved my sprite using analogScreenControl. I am using AndEngine GLES1. i don't want to move my background automatically but i want to move the background as per player moves on the screen with the help of analogScreenControl.

Comment: And, answered the question [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/50482/25768).