# How do I implement an AutoParallax Background in AndEngine GLES1?

Tags: android, andengine, parallax-scrolling

I'm using AndEngine GLES1. In my game, I use AnalogOnScreenControl to move a sprite and when it moves vertically, the background image also moves vertically. I want to do something like this: that is in [this link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s_OeXG6Y9nM&NR=1&feature=fvwp).  I know that AutoParallax Background or BackgroundParallaxScrolling may be used. But how do I use it in my game?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the AutoParallax example code in AndEngine?  It creates the parallax background layers iike this:

```
final Scene scene = new Scene();
final AutoParallaxBackground autoParallaxBackground = new AutoParallaxBackground(0, 0, 0, 5);
final VertexBufferObjectManager vertexBufferObjectManager = this.getVertexBufferObjectManager();
autoParallaxBackground.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(0.0f, new Sprite(0, CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mParallaxLayerBack.getHeight(), this.mParallaxLayerBack, vertexBufferObjectManager)));
autoParallaxBackground.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(-5.0f, new Sprite(0, 80, this.mParallaxLayerMid, vertexBufferObjectManager)));
autoParallaxBackground.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(-10.0f, new Sprite(0, CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mParallaxLayerFront.getHeight(), this.mParallaxLayerFront, vertexBufferObjectManager)));
scene.setBackground(autoParallaxBackground);
```

You can read the rest of the code [here](https://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/AutoParallaxBackgroundExample.java).

Comment: Sorry for my outside question. I want to ask that is it possible to create this type truck in andengine? Because whenever I create any vehicle it stretches out from the joint. I don't know why this happen.

Comment: Ask it in a separate question, or no one will find it!

Comment: I Tried this code but VertexBufferObjectManager is not Working.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? Can you run the built in examples, in general?

Comment: I have red line on VertexBufferObjectManager and i solve my problem with tileCollision example, link of this example is here:[link](http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/tiled-game-t4331.html) Thanks.